# Why am I not able to call a class from this global variable?

Tags: python, class, global-variables

So I have a main file, and then I have my storyline file with all of my functions and a class. I have a class set up for my users' input like their name. Then I want to place that class as a global variable in my main file. When I try to recall the global variable from the main file to a function in the storyline file I get a name Error and the global variable is not recognized. Can someone help fix this name error problem that I have?

mainfile.py

```
try:
    from storyline import *
except:
    print("The file storyline.py is did not load!")


go()
    
mycharacter = character()
 
intro()
```

storyline.py

```
def go()
print("Welcome to the program, I hope you enjoy.")

class character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setname()

    def setname(self):
        while True:
            print("Enter a username.")
            username = input('>:')
                 if username.istitle() == True:
                      self.name = username
                      print("Your username is{}.".format(self.name))
                      break
                else:
                    print("Please type a correct name.")
                    continue
def intro()
global mycharacter
print(f"Hello {mycharacter.name}. Welcome to the program.")
```

Comment: `global class` makes no sense. `class` is a reserved keyword; you can't have a variable named `class`.

Comment: Ok, let me edit it real quick, then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding classes and how they work, and I think some of your indentation is off. What you probably meant to do is something more along these lines:

```
class character:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def intro(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.name}. Welcome to the program.")
```

And then in your other file you could do this:

```
from storyline import *

mycharacter = character("bob")

mycharacter.intro()
```

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out. Thanks for the help.